# Pattern and Matcher is not working in java

Tags: java, regex

Basically I have a simple String Where I need to explicitly restrict characters other than `a-zA-Z0-9`. Before I mention what is wrong here is how I am doing it.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[&=]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Nothing is wrong");
if (m.find()){
    out.print("You are not allowed to have &=.");
    return;
}

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("Itissupposetobeworking");
if (m1.find()){
    out.print("There is something wrong.");
    return;
}
```

The first one works fine, But on the second matcher `m1` always gets to execute `if(m1.find())` even though it doesn't contain any character other than specified in the pattern.

I also tried `Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]")` But still have the same trouble.

and if you might wanna tell, which is better between `String.matches(["a-zA-Z0-9"]);` or the way I am using above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"[a-zA-Z0-9]"` matches (finds a partial match) in a `Itissupposetobeworking`, so the `There is something wrong.` message should be printed. What do you expect? BTW, glee8e suggests using `if (!m1.find()){`.

Comment: well I expect it not to print that because my string that I am matching on doesn't contain any character not being allowed, such as `!@#$%&*(` or etc...

Comment: Then you seem to need `Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");`, right? Or still you may "negate" the `find()` as glee8e suggests.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks bro worked just perfect the way I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to find a partial match in a string that contains a character other than an alphanumeric character:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

or

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\P{Alnum}");
```

The `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` pattern is a negated character class that matches any char other than the ones defined in the class. So, if a string contains any chars other than ASCII letters or digits, your `if (m1.find())` will get triggered and the message will appear.

Note that the whole negated character class can be replaced with a predefined character class `\P{Alnum}` that matches any char other than alphanumeric. `\p{Alnum}` matches any alphanumeric character and `\P{Alnum}` is the reverse class.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` tries to match alphanumeric characters.

So, you will get "There is something wrong." to be printed, if you have a alphanumeric character in the input character sequence of `matcher()`.

Change it to `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` and try.

This tries to match non-alphanumeric characters. So, you will get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the isAlphanumeric Method of org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils yourcode become much more readable. So you need to write

```
if (!StringUtils.isAlphanumeric("Itissupposetobeworking"))
```

instead of

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("Itissupposetobeworking");
if (!m1.find()){
```

Answer (score 1):

When above expression finds a matching it prints "There is something wrong." but if you want to restrict then Use below code.

```
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("a-zA-Z0-9");
    String a = "It$issupposetobeworking";
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(a);
    if (m1.find()){
        System.out.print("There is something wrong.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Everything is fine");
    }
```

If you want the same code to be working with same regular expression in that scenario use this code.

```
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("Itissupposetobeworking");
    if (!(m1.find())){
           out.print("There is something wrong.");
            return;
     }
```